# sapui5 add runtime new control

Tags: controls, sapui5

how can add new control from controller

```js
// create a simple Input field
var oInput1 = new sap.m.Text('input1');
oInput1.setText("Some Text ");
oInput1.setTooltip("This is a tooltip ");

// attach it to some element in the page
oInput1.placeAt("sample1");
```

in view I add holder

try to add text from controller but it not display on screen.

```
var oLayout = this.getView().byId("idholder");  
oLayout.addContent(oInput1);
```

is Run-time add new control is not possible. we have always render control in view and then update it is this good practice we have to follow ?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: there is no error but  oInput1 is not displaying on screen.

Comment: Are you sure? There is no error in the browser console? If your layout exists, and your Text control, then it should be an error in the console... Are other controls rendered properly?

Comment: This is definitely possible. We do this is many place. Here is an example. http://jsbin.com/xukile/1/edit

Comment: sorry to say but it is not working in xml platform.

Answer (score 1):

The `placeAt()` method is normally only used to place a View or App into the HTML.

If you want to add a UI5 control on your view, you can do it this way from the controller:

`this.getView().addContent(oInput1);`

But most likely you won't add controls directly to the view, but rather inside a layout or something inside your view. In that case, do it like this:

```
var oLayout = this.getView().byId("idOfYourSpecificLayoutFrame");
oLayout.addContent(oInput1);
```

Comment: but why it is not displaying on screen?

Comment: then add the Text control to that VBox using the idholder id